# Gauss law in integral form

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Scanning through the lecture notes of my professor I came across some confusing definition, that he calls "**Gauss law in a global form**" which has the following representation $$\oint\boldsymbol{E}\,d\boldsymbol{s}={\iiint}_{Space}{\rho\over\epsilon_0}\,dV.$$

The confusion I am struggling with is the fact that for $\boldsymbol{E}$ being a potential field the work of a force moving a unit charge alongside some closed curve in this field which is clearly represented by $W=\oint\boldsymbol{E}\,d\boldsymbol{s}$ should be equal $0$. However in the above formula it is not equal $0$.

Is that true and if so how can that confusion be resolved and how this equation can be derived?

Comment: Aren't we forgetting to take into account whether or not the field in question is conservative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $\rho$ is the charge density, the integral,

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\iiint_{V} \rho\, dV = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

Now, Gauss' law states that,

$$\iint_{\partial V} E \, dS = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0}$$

Hence, we arrive at your 'global form' by simply equating:

$$\iint_{\partial V} E \, dS =  \frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\iiint_{V} \rho\, dV$$

By the notation,

$$\oint E \, ds$$

**your professor must have meant the surface integral of $E$, not a line integral**. Although using a single integration symbol is misleading, the notation is used in some texts.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing work on a **closed loop**, with an integral on a **closed surface**. What is true is that for eletrostatics, we have
$$\oint_C\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=0,$$
where $C$ is a closed curve, which is Ampère's law. What Gauss law states is that the electric flux over a closed surface is equal to the charge enclosed by it.

Comment: Deriving from @JamalS answer, I just got confused with the notation $\oint$